# How to get value from textField to viewmodel in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

I have an UI as such:

There is a list of products and each product has a list of variants. The user enters the quamtity of variants he needs and clicks on Place order button.

UI:
[image]
[image]

This is the data class I have used

```
data class VariantModal(
    val variantId: String,
    val variantName: String,
    val variantUnit: VariantUnit,
    val productId: String,
    val variantQuantity: Int,
    )


data class Product(
    val productId: String,
    val productName: String,
    val productVariants: List<VariantModal>,
)
```

This is an example of how my list would look like:

```
object SampleProductData {
var items = listOf(
    Product(
        "1_pg",
        "Puliogare Masala",
        listOf(
            VariantModal(
                "pg_30_7",
                "30g 7sheet",
                VariantUnit.ListOfUnits(listOf("Bundle", "Kg")),
                "1_pg",
                0
            ),
            VariantModal(
                "pg_30_14",
                "30g 14sheet",
                VariantUnit.ListOfUnits(listOf("Bundle", "Kg")),
                "1_pg",
                0
            ),
            VariantModal(
                "pg_100",
                "100g",
                VariantUnit.ListOfUnits(listOf("Bundle", "Kg")),
                "1_pg",
                0
            ),
        )
    ),
     Product(....similar to above...),
     Product(....similar to above...),
     Product(....similar to above...),

   )
}
```

I am fetching the list of products and variants from the database and am using it in view model.

```
@HiltViewModel
class ProductsListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: ProductsRepository
) : ViewModel() {


private val itemsList = MutableStateFlow(listOf<Product>())
val items: StateFlow<List<Product>> get() = itemsList
val initialOrder: StateFlow<List<Product>> get() = itemsList

private val itemIdsList = MutableStateFlow(listOf<Int>())
val itemIds: StateFlow<List<Int>> get() = itemIdsList

init {
    init()
}
private fun init() = viewModelScope.launch {
    getData()
}

private suspend fun getData() {
    val products = repository.getAllProducts()
    viewModelScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            itemsList.emit(products)

            Log.d("Console statement", "itemsList is ${itemsList.value}")
            Log.d("Console statement", "items are ${items.value}")
        }
    }
}

fun onItemClicked(itemId: Int) {
    itemIdsList.value = itemIdsList.value.toMutableList().also { list ->
        if (list.contains(itemId)) {
            list.remove(itemId)
        } else {
            list.add(itemId)
        }
    }
}


fun placeOrder(context: Context, viewModel: ProductsListViewModel) = viewModelScope.launch  {
    Log.d("Console Statement", "button clicke ${viewModel.items.value} ")
    Toast.makeText(context, "Button clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
   }
```

Now, I want to get the value the user enters in quantity and store it in variantQuantity when the user clicks on Place order button.

I am displaying all products as a list like this:

```
@Composable
    fun ProductsList(viewModel: ProductsListViewModel) {
    val itemIds by viewModel.itemIds.collectAsState()
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
    ) {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = { TopBar(viewModel) }
        ) { padding ->
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(padding)
            ) {

                itemsIndexed(viewModel.items.value) { index, item ->
                    DisplayProduct(
                        itemModel = item,
                        onClickItem = { viewModel.onItemClicked(index) },
                        expanded = itemIds.contains(index)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The DisplayProduct method calls DisplayVariants method to display each variant. The DisplayVariant method has the textField whose value I want to fetch. I am showing minimal code to keep it simple,

```
@Composable
fun displayVariant(
    item: Product,
    variant: VariantModal,
) {
    var orderedQuantity = 0
    var value by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    TextField(
//        value = variant.variantQuantity.toString(), //This is not working
        value = value,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(backgroundColor = Color.White),
        modifier = Modifier
            .widthIn(min = 32.dp),
        onValueChange = { newText ->
            value = newText

        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.None,
            autoCorrect = false,
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
        )

    )
    if(value != "" ){
        orderedQuantity = value.toInt()
    }
//    updateOrderQuanity(variant, orderedQuantity)
    Log.d("Console Statement", "${variant.variantName}  $value  order placed " )
}
```

I tried

```
value = variant.variantQuantity.toString()
```

to save the value the user enters in variant.variantQuantity but this is not working. It is inturn setting the variant.variantQuantity value` in value. How do i save this value user enters to variant.variantQuantity ? I need this because I want to send the list of products with variants along with thier variantQuantities on click of PlaceOrder button to place the order:

The onCLick of PlaceOrder is like this:

```
 Button(
     onClick = { viewModel.placeOrder(context, viewModel) }
     )
     { Text("Place Order") }
```

To summarize, I have a list of products and each product has a list of variats. The number of products and variants are not fixed everytime. I am fetching the data from db and using a viewmodel. Then i am rendering the data as a list of products. I want to send the data the user enters ( variant quantity - textField) back to the viewmodel so that i can use it in PlaceOrder fuction. HOw to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I guees you need another variable in viewmodel that will contain value of textField, also add an function that will update value of variable in viewmodel.
it will work like:

tap to element **->** change sub variable that contain value of textfield **->** tap to order button **->** call function from viewmodel that will update variable in viewmodel

Comment: Since i'm using a list of products and each product has a list of variants, I dint know how a single variable can hold the value, and also the count of products and variants can change..

Comment: @ChaitraD Instead of a single variable have a List<Product> in your viewModel and when user selects anything, add it to your List.